# How to speed up the image downloading swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the loop that takes the array of imageUrls and make Images from them but it is slow, is there a way to speed it up ?

It looks like this:

```
self.urlArray.forEach() { 
    let photoURL = URL(string: $0)
    guard let url = photoURL else {continue}
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    guard let dataSafe = data else {continue}
    let finishedImage = UIImage(data: dataSafe)
    self.imagesArray.append(finishedImage)
}
```

Comment: you should use sdWebImage to permanently cache those images and not call the task again every time that viewcontroller get called

Comment: Also check `KingFisher`

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari guys I just need to get an array of UIImages fast no need of any of this librarys

Comment: `Data(contentsOf: url)` No. That is not how to do downloading. Use URLSession.

Comment: @komap you can't do like this. making NSData will always lag as it's on main thread too. Also not a good way. Use background thread and use any mechanism that caches your images and doesn't download it everytime

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data in a background thread, then update the UIImageView on the main thread.

```
let photoURL = URL(string: $0)
guard let url = photoURL else {continue}
DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).async{
    //fetch the image data in background
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    guard let dataSafe = data else {continue}
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        //get back to main thread
        let finishedImage = UIImage(data: dataSafe)
        self.imagesArray.append(finishedImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: the OP is using swift 3. Convert your code in swift 3 syntax

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I'm sorry I'm an Objective-C developer, I can't really tell the difference between those Swift versions. Besides, I didn't change the original codes at all, I just added the GCD. Did they change the syntax for GCD as well?

Comment: Yes, the syntax of GCD is changed